# Error when adding google recommended gradle-snippet. Why?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The snipped below is recommended by google. You can see it in its sample test projects of their repository.

```
configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
    println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
        configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
    }
}
```

However, when I add the above snippet my Espresso test fails with an error like below:

- error: cannot access AppCompatActivity
- error: cannot infer type arguments for ActivityTestRule<>

And that is because the AppCompatActivity and stuff added for compile version in gradle like below:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
```

gets removed by the above snippet. Why then is this code snippet good. Or is this dated to older versions of gradle that worked a bit differently. I'm currently using the latest version of gradle v3.5.

Your thoughts matter. What am I missing? Is it safe to assume that the recommendation is dated and that it need not be followed now?